# Highlighting point using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point

How can I highlight a point using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

When I use the function of `centerAndZoom`, I also want to highlight this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
    queryTask.execute(query, function (results) {

        var selectionSymbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol('http://www.clipartandgraphics.com/images/borders/coloroval.gif', 50, 50);
        var graphic = new Graphic(results[0].geometry, selectionSymbol, 50, 50);
        map.graphics.add(graphic);
        map.centerAndZoom(results[0].geometry, 15);

    });
```